# Kicad: Net is graphically connected to bus but not a member of that bus

Tags: kicad, bus

Why is KiCad 7.0.7 complaining that these wires aren't part of the bus, when I've literally labelled the bus `A[18..1]` and `D[15..0]`?

[image]

I tried flipping the sequences (1..18 and 0..15) but that didn't help.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out. The `A[18..1]` and `D[15..0]` labels were apparently "text labels", but should have been "net labels". This wasn't clear from looking at it. I would have posted this as an answer, but SE insists that I complete one of those incredibly annoying broken CAPTCHAs for the privilege, so screw that.

Comment: Labels and text on KiCad schematics use the same font and nearly the same colour. Can you confirm that you are using a label and not text? You can do this by right-clicking on A[18..1] and selecting "Properties".

Comment: ... and I see that I was eight seconds behind you! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @SodAlmighty If you figured it out, please consider posting the solution as an answer. It could be helpful to someone else with the same issue.

Comment: Sure thing. Take the CAPTCHA out of my face and I'll get right on that.